# MySQL NOT LIKE sentence returning "like" results

Tags: mysql, wildcard, sentence

I've been trying to figure this out, but no success yet.  I have two tables, each one with a single varchar column:

```
Table 1: srch(word varchar)
Table 2: tags (tag varchar)
```

The values in each table are:

```
srch: "joining", "tables", "snakes"
tags: "join", "table", "group"
```

What I'm trying to achieve is get the words from search (srch) table that don't match with tags table, however a need to do it using wildcard. So, when I do it with LIKE, it works alright:

```
select s.word from srch s, tags t where s.word like concat(t.tag,"%") group by s.word
```

I need to get the words that don't match with tags table, in this case the word 'snake', so, if I try with `NOT LIKE` it doesn't work:

```
select s.word from srch s, tags t where s.word not like concat(t.tag,"%") group by s.word
```

With this sentence, it returns all the values from srch table.

EDIT:
Sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE `srch` (
  `word` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `srch` VALUES ('joining'),('tables'),('snakes');

CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `tag` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tags` VALUES ('join'),('table'),('group');
```

Any hint for this query?  Thank you.

Comment: Each word from srch table is NOT LIKE at least 1 word in the tags table, therefore it is returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not do a join; instead do a subquery select and use the "NOT EXISTS" check:

```
SELECT s.word
FROM srch s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT tag
  FROM tags t 
  WHERE s.word LIKE CONCAT(t.tag,'%')
)
```

**Result**:

```
// snakes
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, this is what I needed, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by using `WHERE NOT REGEXP` in combination with a `GROUP_CONCAT` to make up a string of all the tags you want to filter out.

```
SELECT word 
FROM srch
WHERE word NOT REGEXP (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tag SEPARATOR '|') FROM tags)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, I tried what you posted, but it returns no results.

Comment: That's strange, I just ran your create tables statements and insert statements and was able to get the word snakes to return.

Comment: @Andino Have a look http://imgur.com/a/1V9NdDV